# two subsets with same minimum, maximum, and median

Tags: combinatorics

> Given 85 subsets of $[11]$ with five elements, prove there are two distinct ones with the same minimum, maximum, and median.

I am starting to really feel hopeless because I can't wrap my head around this basic stuff... How do I count the number of triples $ ( \min A, \operatorname{med}A,\max A)$? I know I want to show there's less than 85 of them but I just don't see how. The inequalities I've written down are $$1\leq\min A\leq 7,3\leq \operatorname{med}A\leq 9,5\leq \max A\leq 11$$ and $$\min A\leq \operatorname{med}A-2<\operatorname{med}+2\leq \max A$$ but I don't see how to count...

I tried doing the ugly thing and just summing over all values of $\operatorname{med}A$, and that got me $84$ but what's the idea? How would I do this for huge numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of triples $(\min (A) ,\text{med} A, \max(A) )$ is equal to the number of $3$-element subsets of $[11]$ that do not contain consecutive elements. (do you see why?).

So we need to count how many $3$-subsets of $11$ do not contain consecutive elements, this is a well known problem. In general the number of $k$-subsets of $[n]$ that do not contain contain consecutive elements is $\binom{n-k+1}{k}$.

So there are $\binom{9}{3}=84$ triples $(\min (A) ,\text{med} A, \max(A) )$. Using the pigeon-hole principle finishes the proof.